# does serialport not return port open errors?

Tags: octave, baud-rate

I intend to test all communication speeds, and stop at the highest. But I can't get information from the serialport to STOP/finish the cycle.

```
clc; clear USB
BaudRate=[115200, 57600, 38400, 19200, 9600, 4800, 2400, 1200, 600, 300]
i=0;
do
 `i++
  disp("--------")
    Baud=BaudRate(i)
    switch Baud
      case (115200)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",115200)
      case (57600)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",57600)
      case (38400)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",38400)
      case (19200)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",19200)
      case (9600)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600)
      case (4800)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",4800)
      case (2400)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",2400)
      case (1200)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",1200)
      case (600)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",600)
      case (300)
        USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",300)
    endswitch
until (STOP)

set(USB,"DataBits",7)
set(USB,"parity","E")
set(USB,"stopbits",1)
set(USB,"timeout",300)
USB
```

I tried to cause an error in opening the port and based on that error, finish.

I tried to open the door again, expecting an error that the door was already open;

I tried with set(USB,"DataBits",7) and waited for it to give me a nonexistent port error;

And handle it through lasterror.message or lasterrror.identifier and thus get a condition to stop the cycle do/until

Comment: I'm just wondering why you used a switch/case instead of `USB = serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0", Baud)`.  In general, you're expected to KNOW the serial port speed you're talking to.

Comment: yes, you are right and in reality my original code was like that, but I had a doubt and decided to remove it, putting the value instead of the Baud variable.
BaudRate=[115200, 57600, 38400, 19200, 9600, 4800, 2400, 1200, 600, 300]
i=0
do
  ++i
  clear USB
  Baud=BaudRate(i)
        switch (SO)
        case "WINDOWS"
                  USB = serialport(porta,Baud);
        case "UNIX/LINUX"
                  USB=serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",Baud)
      case "MAC"
                 USB = serialport("/dev/tty.KeySerial1",Baud)
    endswitch
until (i==length(BaudRate))

Answer (score 0):

I guess everything here works as intended: the `serialport()` call returns an `octave_serialport` instance (see [docs](https://octave.sourceforge.io/instrument-control/package_doc/Serial-Port.html#Outputs-66)).

As Tim Roberts already stated out, you are actually supposed to know the baudrate of the device you're talking to, it doesn't look like your goal would be an algorithm to determine the maximum supported baud rate of your device, therefore I ditch that part completely. For the loop, you'd use [for](https://docs.octave.org/latest/The-for-Statement.html) here.

Just assign the proper port (see [serialportlist()](https://octave.sourceforge.io/instrument-control/package_doc/Serial-Port.html#serialportlist)) and baudrate, then check for the property `Status` on your `octave_serialport` instance - this should give you an indication whether your connection is good or not.

Also, you used the set command wrong, the supported keys are (probably case-sensitive): `baudrate`, `bytesize`, `name`, `parity`, `stopbits`, `timeout`, `requesttosend`, `dataterminalready`.

- `DataBits` has to be `bytesize`.
- `timeout` cannot exceed `255`.

Comment: I can communicate with the motor controller, I just need the port, protocol and controller address to match.
I had the (wrong) expectation of being able to communicate with the highest speed automatically, but one thing is to open and configure the port and another to communicate with the device. In order to communicate, in addition to the physical layer and port configuration, the protocol, and the device address must match. I have no way of knowing if that is the speed of the device until I try to communicate and see if it responds in the affirmative.
Thanks.